# Image pull over multiple K8s nodes

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, containers

When I create a pod, a corresponding image is pulled to the node where the pod is created

Can I have those images shared among the cluster nodes, instead of being stored locally on each node?

Thanks a lot
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you have shared storage across all the Kubernetes nodes. However, it's not a good idea  since typically the place where images get stored is also the place where the container runtime stores its files when it's actually running the container. For example, if you are using Docker, everything gets stored under `/var/lib/docker` or in the case of [containerd](https://containerd.io/) it's `/var/lib/containerd`

So in summary, it's possible with shared files/cluster file systems like [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [Ceph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_(software)), [Glusterfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluster), [AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), etc, but it's not a good idea in my opinion .

Update (@BMitch):

Make sure that the container storage driver you are using [supports the filesystem that you are using](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems).

✌️

Comment: You'll need to be sure your storage driver (graph driver in docker, snapshotter in containerd) supports the distributed filesystem. E.g. overlay2 needs an ext4 or xfs (with specific opts) and won't work on something like NFS. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems

Comment: Thanks for the link  I added it to the answer.